# Can't sudo when logged in with ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, root

I set up a ubuntu machine on my local server. I've got a user with sudo privileges (same password as for login).

I've got passwordless ssh going by putting my rsa public key on the ubuntu machine. So I can ssh in from my mac.  But when I'm logged in over ssh, and I try to sudo, it tells me the password is invalid.

What's the deal?  Here's my /etc/sudoers

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Do you get a password fail (invalid login) error? Or just nothing happens?

Comment: You might want to include your sudo configuration.

Comment: Have you tried logging in with your password, just to check that you have it correct?

Comment: Do you put the right password if the passwords at both machine are different?

Comment: I get 'sorry, try again', so password fail.  I am entering the correct password.  If I'm on the machine itself, user that password for sudo works. Attached sudo config.